# Attach file to Jira using Powershell - Internal Server Error 500

Tags: powershell, jira

I'm trying to attach a file to Jira using Powershell. I was able to attach the file using the Chrome extension "Postman". Using the variables from that I tried to implement that to PowerShell. However, I'm getting the error message below

> Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

My code is below. Would appreciate if someone can help.

Thanks,

```
$uri = "myserver.net/apps/jira/rest/api/jiraissue/attachments"
$username = "username"
$password = "password"
$file = "C:\test\files\jira.txt"
$attachfile = @{body=@{File="$file"}}
$Json = ConvertTo-Json $attachfile

$creds = @{
"Authorization" = "Basic "+[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($username    +":"+$password))
"X-Atlassian-Token"="nocheck"
"Charset"="UTF-8"
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -contenttype "multipart/form-data" -headers $creds -Method Post -body $Json
```

Comment: Why are you using `multipart/form-data` and then sending JSON?

Comment: You have a typo too: `UTP-8`?

Comment: @briantist I actually tried multiple ways. Now I'm kind of stuck on this script. I tried -infile as well but got the same result.

Comment: @EtanReisner yes, It should be UTF. Thank you. I will correct it.

Comment: Have you tried dumping the network traffic from this request and the same request from your browser and comparing them to see what differs? Unless someone very familiar with the jira APIs happens to see this and you have made an obvious error in the data you are submitting it isn't likely you will be able to get much help here I don't think.

Comment: No, that is going to be my next step. I just wanted to make sure I'm not doing anything wrong with the coding part.